# Recovered file size

Tags: file-recovery

recently I accidentally formatted a memory card, but realized immediately and I successfully recovered the images. I used to different paid recovery tools.

The problem that I am having is that some of the recovered files are smaller than normal. 1632 × 1080

Is there any way to find the original size?

Comment: Do you shoot in JPEG or raw?

Answer (score 4):

That depends on how the used recovery program worked: instead of relying on the file system entries, it could have searched the entire memory card for image data and converted that to files. In that case, it's entirely possible that it "recovered" the thumbnails embedded in your real image files only.

If you haven't changed the actual content of your card with any tool yet, i'd recommend using a different tool, unfortunately i don't have personal experience with recent tools to recomend one. Undeleting files on FAT filesystems used to be a fairly trivial procedure, as nothing is actually removed, just marked as "deleted".

Comment: R-Photo from r-tt.com is free and probably the best tool for this.